# UIScrollView overlays NavigationBar

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

i think my ScrollView is located over my navigation bar.
Because my back button doesn't work and instead my function "handleTouchesOne" is called.
I think i have to adjust the height of the scrollView's contentSize but i am doing something wrong.

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, scrollView.frame.size.height);
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
```

Hope someone can help me!

edit: how i init my tap gesture:

```
// One finger single tap

tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchesOne:)];
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; 
tapGesture.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1; // One finger single tap
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
//tapGesture.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];
```

Could it be, that the button does not work because the view is over the nav bar or just links my tap to my function ?

Comment: if your scrollview is transparent, put in some opaque background color to see if it covers your nav controller.

Comment: Seems like it's not the scrollview... when i put red color in the nav bar stays black

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you would have to adjust your scroll view's `frame`, not its `contentSize`.